Android with Microsoft SwiftKey Keyboard - how to get an TAB (tabulator)?
I am on an Android mobile device, I use the Microsoft SwiftKey virtual keyboard in version 9.10.37.20
Where can I find the TAB key, or what is the short cut to fire an TAB event?
I asked Bing Copilot:

Certainly! To insert a tab (tabulator) using the SwiftKey keyboard on Android, follow these steps:
Double Space Key: SwiftKey provides a convenient way to insert a tab. Simply double-tap the space key, and it will insert a tab character.
Remember that the availability of this feature may vary depending on the keyboard app and its settings. Give the double space key a try, and you should be able to insert tabs easily!

But this do not work.
I checked my settings. Double tapping on the space bar -> is doing a dot.
I switched the setting off, but the behavior is still the same.
I also checked my settings -> a long press on space will show the cursor to navigate in text.
Why I need the TAB key?

Bing search is offering the auto-suggestions via tab
In terminals (yes it is possible on mobile)
Edit text in Microsoft Word


Well Bing Copilot's response is not the correct as you have already figured out.

On the keyboard, press the 123 key then press the {&=.
Press ⭲. See cercled key on the image below.


